# Spring JDBC MySQL/MariaDB Data truncated for column 'start_date' at row 1

Tags: java, mysql, database, mariadb, jdbctemplate

I'm using Spring JDBC to store a classifiedAd object to my MariaDB database as follows:

```
public void insert(ClassifiedAd classifiedAd){

   this.jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator(){

      @Override
      public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {

          PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_SQL, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
          ...
          ps.setTimestamp(6, new Timestamp(classifiedAd.getStartDate().getTimeInMillis()));
          ...
          return ps;
        }
   }, keyHolder);
```

The classifiedAd object has a field `private Calendar startDate` that i convert to `java.sql.Timestamp` before mapping it to the corresponding column `start_date datetime null,` in the database.

But when inserting i get the following warning:

```
Dec 13, 2016 10:59:10 AM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.SQLWarnings logAndClearWarnings
INFO: Data truncated for column 'start_date' at row 1
java.sql.SQLWarning: Data truncated for column 'start_date' at row 1
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.getWarnings(MariaDbConnection.java:833)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.getWarnings(NewProxyConnection.java:907)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.SQLWarnings.logAndClearWarnings(SQLWarnings.java:42)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.refurbishResourceOnCheckin(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:285)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.attemptRefurbishResourceOnCheckin(BasicResourcePool.java:1606)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$200(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1228)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
```

I really don't understand why the timestamp is truncated since it's specified [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html) that it's the correct type to use. Any help please?

**EDIT**

These are the values that I get before and after inserting:

Initial value:

```
System.out.println(BankCardDAOTest.expiration_date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/"
    + (classifiedAd.getStartDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/"
    + classifiedAd.getStartDate.get(Calendar.YEAR) + " "
    + classifiedAd.getStartDate.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":"
    + classifiedAd.getStartDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":"
    + classifiedAd.getStartDate.get(Calendar.SECOND));

====> 27/7/2016 4:3:54
```

After inserting and retrieving the object:

```
dao.insert(classifiedAd);
classifiedAd = dao.select(classifiedAd.getId());

====> 27/7/2016 0:0:0
```

Any help please?

Comment: The only thing that I can think of it's date format issue...how are your dates stored on your mariadb tables...can you post the result of a select statement for that field?

Comment: Enable general log on MariaDB server, run your code, you'll see right away what it's sending and why the warning is produced.

Answer (score 0):

`DATEs` should be formated `2016-12-31`.
`DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` values should be formated `2016-12-31 23:59:59`.

Other formats *may* cause the error message you received.

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: Where are the date strings coming from?  What do they look like?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i my database base was generated with `date` columns instead of `datetime` i corrected that now it's working fine...